# How does sound energy conserved?

Tags: acoustics, conservation-laws

> While we talk to someone or hear sound & if we miss a word or sound or voice , that sound could not be searched in atmosphere hence I am clueless
>
> **where does that sound goes?**
>
> **into which form those sound waves get converted**

Answer (score 5):

[Sound waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound#Longitudinal_and_transverse_waves) dissipate energy (i.e., amplitudes damp/decrease) through things like [viscosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity) and "spreading out."  By the latter I mean that if one has a point source, the resulting sound waves will propagate in a spherically symmetric pattern.  To conserve energy/momentum, the [intensity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_intensity) must redistribute over a spherical shell resulting in a reduction with radial distance proportional to r<sup>-2</sup>.

For viscous losses, the energy is converted into random kinetic energy of particles, i.e., heat.  For the intensity dispersion, the loss is just a redistribution of energy over an every increasing spherical shell.